# Who manufactures the enterprise SAS SSD drives sold by HP?

Tags: hp, ssd, hp-proliant

I'm curious about who manufactures the SLC and MLC Enterprise SSD drives sold by HP.

They are labeled "6G SAS Hot Plug Enterprise Performance Solid State Drives" and "6G SAS Hot Plug Enterprise Mainstream Solid State Drives", respectively, in the product catalogs (e.g #632504-B21). They're offered in 100GB, 200GB and 400GB capacities.

Are these STEC drives? Pliant? Another manufacturer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>According to HP, HP is the manufacturer of [these drives](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10360876/mfg_partno/632504-B21).</strike>

Sites selling it, like [CDW](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/HP-Enterprise-solid-state-drive-400-GB-SAS/2433536.aspx#TS), list HP as the manufacturer as well.

Correcting my answer, as I looked a little harder after @Jason Bergs comment:

It looks like [SanDisk is the manufacturer](http://www.cdrlabs.com/News/sandisk-launches-lightning-6gbps-sas-enterprise-ssds.html), who recently purchased Pliant Technology.  There's a [Network World article](http://wwww.networkworld.com/newsletters/stor/2011/052311stor1.html) on the acquisition that mentions OEM customers of Pliant being EMC, HP, and IBM.

Comment: HP is the brand but they do not manufacture these drives. They rebrand what somebody else makes

Comment: You got it! I just found a photo of the HP and the Sandisk/Pliant because they actually match. Thank you.

Comment: And a +1 from me for going back and finding the right answer :-)